# What branch of service and rank is this 1860 photo?

Tags: military, identification

This is a cabinet photo taken by Kelley's in New York, but we are having a difficult time identifying his branch of service and rank. Any leads to this genealogical effort would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Picture of uniform]

[image: Rear of photograph]

Comment: Please provide us with ***everything*** you know about both the subject of the photo and the photo itself.

Comment: I wonder how accurate your estimated ate of c. 1860 is? The things that he is wearing on his shoulders look like things that were part of the full dress uniforms of US cavalry officers after about 1873 if I remember correctly. Therefore he would probably have to be a member of either a regular army unit that wore those shoulder things, or a militia unit that wore them. Or possibly a student at some sort of military academy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We don't have a lot of information for this and our other inherited photos, but this is much appreciated.